# Reconciling multiple data sets

Tags: data-structures, consensus

I am trying to reconcile multiple data sets to identify differences from the consensus.  There could be 100 sets of the same data with maybe 30,000 records in each.  Each set has the same columns but may not have the same rows i.e. a record for Person1 may only exist in one set or may be in all of them.  I want to identify only records that differ and to report on the differences.  Probably easier to give an example e.g.

**Set1:**

**Person  Sex DOB        salary etc**

Person1 M   12/12/2000 100000 etc

Person2 F   11/11/1999 200000 etc

**Set2:**

**Person  Sex DOB        salary etc**

Person2 F   11/11/1999 250000 etc

Person3 M   10/10/1998 150000 etc

**Set3:**

**Person  Sex DOB        salary etc**

Person1 M   12/12/2000 100000 etc

Person2 F   11/11/1999 250000 etc

Person3 M   10/10/1998 150000 etc

I would want to report that Set1 has a different salary for Person2 than the consensus (Set2 and Set3 have 250000 but Set1 has 200000).  Nothing would be reported for Person1 or Person 3 as all sets have identical information for them.

What's the best technology to do this?  Relational database with SQL statements?  some kind of vector DB?  Hadoop?  Statistical software?

Thanks in advance,

Robin

Comment: You first have to define what "consensus" means. If you have 100 sets of data, all of which contain a record for Person 2, and there are, say, 10 different salaries represented, what is the consensus? The salary with the most entries? So if one salary is represented 20 times, another 19 times, and others are represented fewer times, is 20 the consensus?

Comment: Good point!  Clearly if 90 sets have 100,000 and 10 have something else, the consensus is 100,000 and I'd report to the 10 that they are probably wrong.  If 50 sets have 100,000 and 50 have 150,000, I'd want to report to them all that there is no consensus and they should recheck the data.  Perhaps, if more than, say 40% agree this should be reported e.g. "70% report 100,000 and 30% report 150,000.  You report 100,000"  If no more than 40% agree, I'd like to report to all that there is no consensus and the data is suspect.  I'd like to refine the consensus level, or make it a parameter.

Comment: How will you identify Person1,2,3? Will you have some sort of identification number (SSN) to identify them? It seems to me that if you may be leaning towards just a simple hash table to compare person1 between all sets.

Comment: I'm using "Person1/2/3" just as an example.  In reality, there will be multiple types of data but they keys will be common across sources (or easily enrichable to be common).  So, you could use SSN as a proxy for now.  I'm currently leaning towards something simple so the process would be: 1. each time a new set is uploaded, construct a superset of keys in a new table, then for each value, calculate the consensus in a new table, then report for each client comparing their data to the consensus.  I could do this using SQL/Perl/etc.  Any thoughts?

Comment: One "parameter" that will influence answers to this question is whether you need a system to handle this task, or whether you want to manage this manually and don't need to perform this task multiple times. If you build a system for this, it can run autonomously, and handle new data as it becomes available. This requires more planning, but will be a better solution long-term. If you don't need a system, you can write a script. The script would run through all your data and produce some sort of report, but would be less amenable to adding more data after you're done. Is this a common scenario?

Comment: I need a system.  These files will be uploaded daily from different sources.  I'm assuming FTP flat file for now, with an import script.  Then I need to trigger the processing I need.  Just trying to figure out what sort of engineering help I'll need!

Comment: Writing a script or simple program will likely offer significant flexibility going forward. You could have a function that takes a set of files, or a set of structs representing the different rows/sets, and another function which decides whether there is a consensus - and what it is.

Comment: Does anyone know of specific algorithms for agreeing consensus?  See the second post after the initial description.  Statistically, is there a confidence level I could compute, given a number of observations of the same data and choosing a majority?